# How to remove space below footer in html website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap.I a creating website in which i get space after footer when minimize it to mobile size.I made margin:0;padding:0.Still not working.HTML code  is

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF9933;
}

#footer_img {
  margin-top: -50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}

.footer1 {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid section">
  <div class="row">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/Content_bg.png" alt="content image" id="content_img"/>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="container-fluid footer1">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="images/footer2.png" alt="footer image" id="footer_img"/> 
</footer>
```

Comment: share link so that we can explain you the reason in a better way

Answer (score -1):

In footer image you have the footer image bound to the top of the page, actually above it. Running your code in jsfiddle from #footer_img I removed both margin-top and height and it appeared to work. Let me know if it doesn't.

If I am understanding your question correctly the problem is that the padding isn't appearing.

Well for starters when using bootstrap you can only have one container, and here you have two.

```
div class="container-fluid section"

footer class="container-fluid footer1"
```

This might be what is causing the problem. Correct that and reupload if it isn't resolved. Thanks

Comment: @Brad Larson, Thanks I'm still trying to learn how to edit/proper etiquette on here.